# I'm getting the error "returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression"

Tags: c#

I have highlighted the code below which is giving me this error. What I want to do is if the value of `nserved` is less than or equal to 4 then return the value however if it is more than 4 then it defaults the value to 0.

P.S. I've not long started programming and I'm trying to keep my code as simple as possible. Thank you for your help.

```
public class FoodItem
{
    private String Name;
    private String Description;
    private int NumberServed;
    private double Cost;

    public FoodItem(String fname, String fdescription, int nserved, double fcost)
    {
        Name = fname;
        Description = fdescription;
        NumberServed = nserved;
        Cost = fcost;
    }

     public string getFoodName()
     {
         return Name;
     }

     public void setFoodName(string fname)
     {
         Name = fname;
     }

     public string getFoodDescription()
     {
         return Description;
     }

     public void setFoodDescription(string fdescription)
     {
         Description = fdescription;
     }

     public int getNumberPeople()
     {
         return NumberServed;
     }

     public void setNumberPeople(int nserved)
     {
         NumberServed = nserved;

         // Checks to see if the maximum number of people has been exceeded.
         if (nserved <= 4)
         {
             return nserved;
         }
         else
         {
             return 0;
         }
     }

     public double getFoodCost()
     {
         return Cost;
     }

     public void setFoodCost(double fcost)
     {
         Cost = fcost;
     }
}
```

Comment: Your method signature is `public void setNumberPeople(int nserved)` , you can't return anything from this method, you can only `return;`

Comment: A method whose name begins with `set` but which returns a value is an unusual pattern.  Is your intention to create minimum and maximum for `NumberServed`?

Comment: It looks like you trying to re-implement properties (`get`/`set`) - please consider using built-in properties instead inventing your own. Also try to use default C# naming conventions for public code: function names should start with capital letter `SetFoodCost`, try to avoid partial words (like f-words in your sample :)).

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use normal properties with getters/setters instead:

```
public class FoodItem
{
    public const in MaxNumberOfPeople = 4;
    // no extra logic for this field
    public string Name {get;set;} 

    // this one have backing field and some special logic for set:
    private int numberServed;
    public int NumberServed {
       get { return numberServed;}
       set 
       {
           /* some special code here if needed*/
           numberServed = value > MaxNumberOfPeople ? 0 : value;
       } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature is `public void setNumberPeople(int nserved)` which means it is returning essentially nothing, or at least no usable data.

If you want to return an integer, change that signature to:

`public int setNumberPeople(int nserved)`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a strange method that declares it returns nothing (is `void`), sets a private field to the number passed, then tries to return a constrained value. It's likely the following is more what you are after:

```
 public void setNumberPeople(int nserved)
 {
     if (nserved <= 4)
     {
         NumberServed =  nserved;
     }
     else
     {
         NumberServed = 0;
     }
 }
```

This is long-winded code though and can be more neatly expressed as:

```
 public void setNumberPeople(int nserved)
 {
     NumberServed = (nserved <= 4) ? nserved : 0;
 }
```

Finally, the whole class looks like you know Java and are writing Java for the C# compiler. C# supports first-class properties and the whole thing can be rewritten as:

```
public class FoodItem
{
    private int numberServed;

    public FoodItem(String fname, String fdescription, int nserved, double fcost)
    {
        FoodName = fname;
        FoodDescription = fdescription;
        NumberPeople = nserved;
        FoodCost = fcost;
    }

    public string FoodName { get; set; }
    public string FoodDescription { get; set; }
    public int NumberPeople() { get; set; }
    public double FoodCost { get; set; }

    public int NumberPeople
    {
        get { return numberServed; }
        set { numberServed = value <= 4 ? value : 0; }
    }
}
```